# Numerators of close rational approximations to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, pi, diophantine-approximation

Define a rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ to be $\epsilon$-close to $\pi$ if

$$\left|\pi - \frac{p}{q}\right| \leq \frac{1}{q^{\mu-\epsilon}}$$

where $\mu$ is the irrationality measure of $\pi$, defined to be the largest real $\mu$ such that the above inequality has infinitely many solutions in positive integral $p, q$ where $\gcd(p, q) = 1$.

I'm trying to prove that there exist infinitely many $\epsilon$-close rational numbers to $\pi$ such that $p$ is even, and I can't figure out where to start.

1. How would I go about starting to prove this?
2. How hard would this be to prove (how difficult does this problem seem to people who know more about this field than I do?)
3. Is it likely that generalizations of this result are of a similar difficulty?
4. (more of a meta question) Is this the type of question that's better suited for MathOverflow?

I think the generalization I'd really like to prove is that for all positive integral $n\geq 2$ and positive integral $0<k<n, \gcd(k, n) = 1$ there exist infinitely $\epsilon$-close rational numbers to $\pi$ such that $p \equiv 0 \mod n$ and $q \equiv k \mod n$.

Comment: I asked a version of this a while ago on MO, and the answers (though in the general case, not specific to $\pi$) are complicated: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171457/can-we-get-good-rational-approximations-in-all-residue-classes

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for linking that. That paper that you linked looks very interesting, and I think it works for what I need it to if $\mu = 2$, so thanks! How difficult (if it's even possible) do you think it would be to extend that result to an exponent of $\mu$ instead of $2$?

Comment: It's hard to gauge; I think things would get more complicated still in the $\mu\gt2$ case.  And in the case of $\pi$, given that we don't even know the irrationality measure, things are likely to be harder still. I'd be very surprised if anything substantially more than that result was known here.